# TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'. после проверки

Tags: typescript

TypeScript выбрасывает ошибку `TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'` даже после проверки.
Код проблемного класса (остальные методы убраны ибо в них возникает такая же ошибка). Ошибка возникает в методе onMessage на строке с вызовом метода `forEach` (выделяется как ошибка `this.handlers[event]`).

```
import EVENTS from '@/data/constants/events';

type EventPayload = Record<string, unknown>;
type EventHandler = (payload: EventPayload) => void;
type Handlers = {
  [key in EVENTS]?: EventHandler[]
};

class MessageBroker {
  handlers: Handlers = {};

  onMessage({ event, payload }: { event: EVENTS, payload: EventPayload }): void {
    if (this.handlers[event]) {
      this.handlers[event].forEach((handler) => handler(payload));
    }
  }
}

const messageBroker = new MessageBroker();

export default messageBroker;
```

```
// @data/constants/events

enum events {
  CREATE_PANEL = 'create-panel'
}

export default events;
```

Тип Handlers, как я задумал, должен позволять быть переменной либо пустым объектом, либо объектом с ключом из enum EVENTS и значением массива функций типа EventHandler. Поправьте меня пожалуйста, если я не прав.
И соответственно я проверяю на наличие в принципе такого ключа, как переданного аргументом метода как event, и если он есть - хочу проитерировать его, так как согласно типу Handlers он должен быть массивом функций.
Но это не работает, даже если добавить абсурдную проверку на все подряд в этом методе. (выделять как ошибку начинает в самом условии в последнем "множителе" на `this.handlers[event].forEach`)

```
onMessage({ event, payload }: { event: EVENTS, payload: EventPayload }): void {
  if (this && this.handlers && this.handlers[event] && typeof this.handlers[event] === 'object' && this.handlers[event].forEach) {
     this.handlers[event].forEach((handler) => handler(payload));
  }
}
```

Заранее спасибо за ответы! Хочется разобраться в чем причина, так как просто найти обходной путь конечно же можно.

Comment: сохрани `this.handlers[event]` в переменную перед проверкой и проверяй и используй эту переменную

Comment: @Grundy Сработало, но не совсем понимаю почему.. Спасибо! Можешь рассказать куда копать для понимания?

Comment: судя по всему проверяльщик типов не работает с выражениями, и проверяет только значения переменных, а для выражения: метод либо свойство по имени в строке вычисляет каждый раз тип